# Syntax error while passing the values

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass the value one form to another. I am getting ") missing" but I am not getting where I am going wrong. Is this the correct way to call all the parameters?

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
$("#div1").load("http://ppp.gkdsjfgk.com/wp-content/themes/thestory/compare-form-site.php?loanamt=" + 
      <?php echo $_POST['loanAmt']; ?>."&occupation=" + 
      <?php echo $_POST['occupation']; ?>."&rateType=" + 
      <?php echo $_POST['rateType']; ?>."&age=" + 
      <?php echo $_POST['age']; ?>."&city=" + 
      <?php echo $_POST['city']; ?> );
```

Comment: Open developer's console and see what going on there.

Comment: look at the rendered source.... And the values should be encoded...

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list i am getting this error

Comment: Using `+`, `.` - do you understand what's going on?

Comment: Concatenate in PHP is period, in javascript is +. Use the wrong one in the wrong space, and you get errors. In this case, look at you rendered code.

Comment: I am not getting this. please anyone can explain

Comment: `<?php echo $_POST['occupation']; ?>."&rateType=" ` < should be a `+` not a `.`

Comment: loanamt=" + <?php echo $_POST['loanAmt']; ?>+"&occupation=" + <?php echo $_POST['occupation']; ?>+"&rateType=" + <?php echo $_POST['rateType']; ?>+"&age=" + <?php echo $_POST['age']; ?>+"&city=" + <?php echo $_POST['city']; ?> );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong concatenator just after each of your PHP brackets `?>.` The dot (the concatenator for PHP) should be replaced with `+` (the JavaScript concatenator) like this `?> +`.

```
$("#div1").load(
    "http://ppp.gkdsjfgk.com/wp-content/themes/thestory/compare-form-site.php?loanamt=" + 
    <?php echo $_POST['loanAmt']; ?> + "&occupation=" + 
    <?php echo $_POST['occupation']; ?> + "&rateType=" + 
    <?php echo $_POST['rateType']; ?> + "&age=" + 
    <?php echo $_POST['age']; ?> + "&city=" + 
    <?php echo $_POST['city']; ?> 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing PHP and JavaScript concatenation. (.) is used in PHP and (+) is used in JavaScript

concatenation in PHP is like this:

```
$val = 'Your'.' '.'val';
```

concatenation in JavaScript is like this:

```
var val = 'Your'+' '+'val';
```

so your code should be like this:

```
$("#div1").load("http://ppp.gkdsjfgk.com/wp-content/themes/thestory/compare-form-site.php?loanamt="+<?php echo $_POST['loanAmt'];?>+"&occupation="+<?php echo $_POST['occupation']; ?>+"&rateType="+<?php echo $_POST['rateType']; ?>+"&age="+<?php echo $_POST['age']; ?>+"&city="+<?php echo $_POST['city']; ?> );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, first make a variable so that it will be easier to modify if there's still wrong, just comment here what's the error after you try this code.

```
<script>

    // set variable
    var loadAmt = "<?php echo isset($_POST['loanAmt']) ? $_POST['loanAmt'] : ''; ?>";
    var occupation = "<?php echo isset($_POST['occupation']) ? $_POST['occupation'] : ''; ?>";
    var rateType = "<?php echo isset($_POST['rateType']) ? $_POST['rateType'] : ''; ?>";
    var age = "<?php echo isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : ''; ?>";
    var city = "<?php echo isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : ''; ?>";
    // your load variable
    var loadVar = "http://ppp.gkdsjfgk.com/wp-content/themes/thestory/compare-form-site.php?loanamt="+loadAmt+"&occupation="+occupation+"&rateType="+rateType+"&age="+age+"&city="+city;
    // load to specified div
    $('#div1').load(loadVar);

</script>
```